# foreach file image directory Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I'm learning how to use Laravel. I just learned how to do a foreach loop in my database for articles. Now I want to try the same but loop for all the images in my image directory. How can I do this? Is it similar to this :

```
@foreach (File::allFiles(public_path().'/assets/image/') as $file)
{
    $filename = $file->getRelativePathName();
    echo HTML::image('public/assets/img/'.$filename, $filename);
}
@endforeach
```

also in my article page I was able to apply the foreach to a li object, how can I do the same for my images?

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <div class="grid-item">
        <li><a href="/article/{{$article->id}}">{{$article->photo}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="/article/{{$article->id}}">{{$article->title}}</a></li>
        {!! Form::open(['url' => 'article' ]) !!}
        {!! Form::file('image', null) !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::hidden('user_id', $article->user_id, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Like', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
    <!--{!! Form::open(['url' => 'article' ]) !!}


    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('like', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
    <img href="#popup" data-toggle="modal" class="grid-item1" src="/assets/image/article/thumbnail/{{$article->photo}}">
    -->

@endforeach
```

Comment: What is the output from your initial attempt?

Comment: { $filename = $file->getRelativePathName(); echo HTML::image('public/assets/img/'.$filename, $filename); } { $filename = $file->getRelativePathName(); echo HTML::image('public/assets/img/'.$filename, $filename); } { $filename = $file->getRelativePathName(); echo HTML::image('public/assets/img/'.$filename, $filename); } { $filename = $file->getRelativePathName(); echo HTML::image('public/assets/img/'.$filename, $filename); } { $filename = $file->getRelativePathName(); echo HTML::image('public/assets/img/'.$filename, $filename); } { $filename = $file-

Comment: I mean the html output

Comment: my first attempt with the articles brought back this..<!--<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/article" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="KytSFTcVqdtb5i5BIPaFz8eLAUHMk7vyH96Bi91O">


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="like">
   </div>
</form>
                                    <img href="#popup" data-toggle="modal" class="grid-item1" src="/assets/image/article/thumbnail/">
                                    -->

Comment: You don’t need the curly braces inside the `@foreach`/`@endforeach` statements.